# Why does Firefox fire mousemove outside an overflow:hidden element while dragging, but not with overflow:visible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I just found this and can't explain myself why it behaves like this. But this is exactly the behavior I want to implement. Try this example:

```js
const redBar = document.querySelector("#red");
const greenBar = document.querySelector("#green");

redBar.onmousemove = moveHandle;
redBar.onclick = moveHandle;
greenBar.onmousemove = moveHandle;
greenBar.onclick = moveHandle;

function moveHandle(event) {
 
 if (event.buttons === 1 || event.type === "click") {
  let y = (event.y - this.offsetTop) - 7.5;
  
  if (y < -7.5) {
   y = -7.5;
  } else if (y > this.offsetHeight - 7.5) {
   y = this.offsetHeight - 7.5;
  }
  
  this.querySelector(".handle").style.top = y + "px";
 }
}
```

```css
body {
 display: flex;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 margin: 0;

}

.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 200px;
}

.no-overflow {
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.handle {
 position: relative;
 width: 60px;
 height: 15px;
 top: -7px;
 left: -15px;
 background: #222d;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div id="red" class="bar">
  <div class="handle"></div>
 </div>

 <div id="green" class="no-overflow bar">
  <div class="handle"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Try moving the handle of the red bar and of the green bar. On the green bar you can move the handle once you had the mouse down on the bar and keep holding down the button, even if you are not above the bar.

The only difference is that on the green one (except the color) the overflow 
is hidden.

Is this a bug or did I forget something? (I'm on Firefox btw)

And whats the best way to implement a behavior like this without the overflow being hidden because when i try to do this, it always get pretty messy. (I know there are sliders but maybe in case I want something like this with 2 dimensions)

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

By further testing, I noticed that this stops working when user-select is none. Then it behaves like the element without the hidden overflow.

Comment: Usually this is done by listening mousedown on the element, and when that fires, stop listening mousedown and start to listen mouseup and mousemove on `document`. When mouseup fires, stop listening mouseup and mousemove, and start listening mousedown on the element again.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly how I do that usually but this was getting pretty messy (atleast when I was less experienced with javascript than I am now). Also that's a lot more code than just setting the parents overflow to hidden and archive the exact same thing.

Comment: It's not messy at all, but needs more code. You could make a Class or prototype object, and easily implement this for multiple elements by creating new instances.

Comment: yeah thats true. wasn't event much lines of code. I don't know what kind of bullshit code I wrote when I did that before (didn't use classes for sure). thanks for the hints. now the bug does bother me because the value of the green bar still changes when I'm currently changing the value of the red one. Changing user-select to none is the fix for this.

Comment: I'm bad with ES6 classes, I still find old good prototypes more flexible, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/3f80p9az/4/).

Comment: I'm pretty new to oop in JavaScript so I started using ES6 classes right away. As I'm coming from Java this also feels more familiar for me. I'll post my approach later if you're intrested.

Answer (score 1):

The `mousemove` misfiring in Firefox due to `overflow:hidden` looks like [bug 620513](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=620513) / [bug 1352061](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1352061).

As for achieving this effect without relying on the bug, [Teemu correctly notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57521691/javascript-css-firefox-bug-with-mousemove-event-any-ways-to-implement-same-beha#comment101510284_57521691) that:

> Usually this is done by listening mousedown on the element, and when that fires, stop listening mousedown and start to listen mouseup and mousemove on document. When mouseup fires, stop listening mouseup and mousemove, and start listening mousedown on the element again.

Pointer Events API ([`.setPointerCapture()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setPointerCapture)) is the modern way to achieve this behavior (needs a [polyfill](https://github.com/aarongloege/pointer) for Safari and older browsers).